# downloading S3 files using express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I am working on a side project. Users are able to upload files to S3, view them and be able to download to their machine.

I am at a loss in terms of how to download files from S3. My front end is on React, and the UI should be pretty straight forward. Click a download button, get a pop up screen to save the file on a user's machine. But what is the best approach to handling this?